# Changing eventClick to occur only on double click in jQuery FullCalendar plugin

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Is it possible for the eventClick to happen on a double click rather than a single click?  I know of ways in which I can do this but is there an elegant way of doing this using this plugin without changing the core?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You should modify the plugin. You need to modify the event handlers such as:

```
    eventElementHandlers: function (event, eventElement)
    {
        var view = this; 
        eventElement
        .click(function (ev)
        {
            if (!eventElement.hasClass('ui-draggable-dragging') &&
                !eventElement.hasClass('ui-resizable-resizing'))
            {
                return view.trigger('eventClick', this, event, ev);
            }
        })
        .dblclick(function (ev)
        {
            return view.trigger('dblclick', this, event, ev);
        })
        .hover(
            function (ev)
            {
                view.trigger('eventMouseover', this, event, ev);
            },
            function (ev)
            {
                view.trigger('eventMouseout', this, event, ev);
            }
        );
    },
```

You can add in the same way more events. [Here](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/) you can find the list of events that comes with jQuery. For right click and some other event there are plugings.